# Android stop camera from saving to gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I am working on an app that uses the phones camera app, and on some phones the images is being saved to the gallery and on other phones not. Is there a way to make the camera app not save that image at all? I want to save the image another place, under another name and not visible in gallery(If possible). One idea iv'e come up with is to delete the image from gallery right after it leaves the camera app, but dont like that idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Camera from saving photo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412047/keep-camera-from-saving-photo)

Comment: so you think there is no way around?